# Tokenize2 with default added values

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize2

I am using Tokenize2

```
<select id="tokenize" multiple="multiple" class="tokenize">
  @foreach (var item in Model.Listpositions) {
    <option>@item.PositionName</option>
  }
</select>
```

this is work.User auto complete from my datasouce which include more than 10000 positions.When user click save button I insert added values to database in insert page.This is work

But I hava edit page.In edit page I give same datasource and autocomplete works but I want to set that select with values which added in insert page like this photo.I want to set that [image]

Answer (score 4):

> you can simply use .trigger event to fill you data.

```
 <script>
     $('#tokenize').tokenize2().trigger('tokenize:tokens:add', ['value', 'Text', true]);
 </script>
```